# javascript tips - how to add object w/o the need to write a lot of ifs

Tags: javascript

I have an object that has 3 parameters. in some cases one of the parameters can be empty.

Is there quick & clean coding for doing the below code w/o getting an error if one of the parameters doesn't exist.

```
var str = object.x &&  + object.y + object.z
```

Comment: You mean properties of an object?

Comment: One way to do it would be define your own shortcut function.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. Also, it doesn't trigger any errors for me with an empty `object`

Comment: var str = (object.x || 0)  + (object.y || 0) + (object.z || 0) shortest and simplest way

Comment: With your current example, an error would only occur if `object` itself is null or undefined – `var str = object && (object.x + object.y + object.z);`. The `x`, `y`, and `z` properties aren't required to exist on `object`, as the property accessor (period) will just return `undefined` for them by default.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - Perhaps by "error" the OP just meant an undesired result, like `'testundefinedsomething'` instead of `'testsomething'`? (A logic error rather than an exception.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One clean and simple way to add them would be:

```
var str = (object.x || '') + (object.y || '') + (object.z || '');
```

Comment: There are a few possible gotchas if the values could be the number 0 or the boolean false, but this is a good quick and dirty way to do it.

Comment: Yes, this answer assumes the values are strings if they are present.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own function which will do that for you:

```js
function sumExisting() {
  function isValid(n) {
    return typeof n == 'number' && !isNaN(n) && isFinite(n);
  }
  
  var args = Array.prototype.filter.call(arguments, isValid);
  return args.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
}

// Demo:
var o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 3.4,
  c: false,
  d: 'qwe',
  e: null
};

var sum = sumExisting(o.a, o.b, o.c, o.d, o.e, o.f);
console.log(sum);
```

Note that this implementation is just an example to show the idea, which sums up valid numbers.
I like this approach because it lets you describe your own rules easily. You can easily modify it such that it replaces undefined values with a constant value; or make it concatenate strings; or output debug messages in case of `null` value etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var str=((object.x==undefined)?0:object.x)+((object.y==undefined)?0:object.y)+((object.z==undefined)?0:object.z)
```

Or a clean way

```
var a=(object.x==undefined)?0:object.x;
var b=(object.y==undefined)?0:object.y;
var c=(object.z==undefined)?0:object.z;

var str=a+b+c;
```

If str is a string then instead of 0 you should use empty string.

Comment: If the end result is assigned to something called `str` I suspect defaults of empty strings might be better than defaults of zero, but in any case wouldn't it be neater to use `var str = (object.x || 0) + (object.y || 0)...`?

Comment: Definitely if str is a string. And my ans is true if str is an integer. Ok I am going to mention it.